# php - CSV table with button to move between pages

Tags: php

I need my script will show at the bottom of the table a next and previous page button

any ideas?

The code:

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

echo '<table border="1">';

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '<thead><tr>';
    }else{
        echo '<tr>';
    }

    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        if(empty($data[$c])) {
           $value = "&nbsp;";
        }else{
           $value = $data[$c];
        }
        if ($row == 1) {
            echo '<th>'.$value.'</th>';
        }else{
            echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
        }
    }

    if ($row == 1) {
        echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';
    }else{
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $row++;
}

echo '</tbody></table>';
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated!................................................

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: @KarolSamborski edited my question.